# How to load javascript facebook api SYNCHRONOUSLY ...?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to load facebook api ( javascript SDK) synchronously. I have seen this code on facebook developers.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
status     : true, // check login status
cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
</script>
```

and also on reference to another link 
http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-javascript-sdk-best-practices/58/
is is mentioned that "But you need to make sure you don’t define FB in your own JS code or libraries!"...............

I am confused ....!
Please help me....

Comment: what is confusing you exactly?

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing looks fine.

The instruction that you've seen, "But you need to make sure you don’t define FB in your own JS code or libraries!" is simply a warning to not declare a variable named `FB` in your application, or you will hide the Facebook SDK.

In your code, on the very next line, you could begin making calls with `FB.api` or any of the other methods.

Does that help?

Comment: hi,
I passed application id to the above mentioned code.
After that i called,FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { alert(response.status);
});
But it is showing error "e.root is undefined."

Comment: Also remove "async defer" from this line:
<script type="text/javascript" async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>

Answer (score -9):

Add the below code after opening html  tag

```
    <div id="fb-root">
    </div>

    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'Your APP ID',
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow server to access session
                xfbml: true, // parse XFBML
                oauth: true
            });
        };
     (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
   </script>
```

This code will load the javascript SDK asynchronously.

Comment: I am using these lines in my project to load the JS SDK asynchronously and its working fine for me.. May i know the reason for down vote, so that I can be more clear in my answer.

Comment: The question was how to load the sdk SYNCHONOUSLY, as was capitalized in the title. Your code loads is Asynchronously. Just in case you hadn't noticed in the 6 months since you posted this answer.